# Reclassification machine learning measuring fatigue

Tags: machine-learning, classification, logistic-regression

I am very new to data science/ML field, so I apologize in advance if my logic may seem confusing.

I would like to know if it's possible to perform reclassification on a dataset?
So the process I want to do goes like this:

I want to classify physical fatigue using Machine Learning.
I will make the person perform some exercises while collecting sensor data.

I'm going to collect sensor data from smartphone (acceleration, gyroscope, etc) and also EMG, Heart Rate and I'll ask the person to state how tired they are feeling from 1-10 (Rating for Perceived Exertion or RPE).

Then I'll take EMG, Heart Rate data as independent variables and the RPE as dependent variable or labeling method (No-fatigue, mild , moderate  and heavy represented as 1,2,3,4) and perform a logistic regression for classification.

After I get the results I want to use the labels obtained from the logistic regression classification and take the smartphone sensor data as my features and classify my data based on those labels.

I would like to know if this approach would correct or if there is any other way.

I want to do something similar like what the authors did on this paper:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5923826/

http://dcollection.hanyang.ac.kr/public_resource/pdf/000000107948_20200302195433.pdf  Pages [78-81 and 93-99]

Comment: What is the reason to not directly learn a classification model from the smartphone data as predictors and the RPE score (or a binary simplification/summary of it) as target variable?

Comment: I wanted to use a different measure other than RPE as target variable for classifying the smartphone data, as previous studies had done so, RPE is very subjective and I was trying to use more objective measures such as the Heart Rate and EMG signals combined(since using only one can't measure fatigue as a whole).